# Not getting Form values on http post with ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

```js
submitdata(){
    let url = "my api url here ";
   let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      })
  };
  let body = JSON.stringify({
    fData : this.contactForm.value.name
  });
  this.http.post(url,body,httpOptions)
  .subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
  })
  }
```

```html
 <form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="submitdata()" >

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)] = "name" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Contact</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="contact" [(ngModel)] = "contact"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)] = "email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

   
  </ion-list>
    <button ion-button type="submit" >Submit Form</button>
  </form>
```

Hi i am sending form data to server using http post method , but i am getting empty array in my console.I tried in many ways but not getting the form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you, You are confusing formContol and ngModel, You can either use one thing is enough, Here iam used Template driven sample method.

Html File,

```
<form #contactForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitdata(contactForm.value)" >

    <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)] = "name" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Contact</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" name="contact" [(ngModel)] = "contact"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)] = "email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
    <button ion-button type="submit" >Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Typescript File,

```
  name:any;
    email:any;
    contact:any;

    submitdata(formValue:any){
            console.log("Form Value",formValue);
        }
```

Here is an sample output screen

[image]

For more Reference Visit official site,

https://angular.io/guide/forms

Make sure you have to include `FormsModule` in app.module.ts file,

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

 imports: [
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
```

Iam used two way data binding method, you can pass value component to html file also,

```
constructor() {
 this.name="Muthu";
 this.email="muthu@gmail.com";
 this.contact="1234567890"
}
```

like this,